# Google Play 64-bit requirement-release is not compliant

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I am trying to upload my app to play console but cannot. Every time it is giving me error This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement.The following APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but they only have 32-bit native code: [29]

Below is my current app level gradle file

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'


defaultConfig {

    applicationId "com.gogreenfood9z.foodcart"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 30
    versionName "1.0"
    ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
    multiDexEnabled true

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    //added for onesignal
    manifestPlaceholders = [
            onesignal_app_id               : 'a7050dd0-9b02-4b5a-a2f2-fcdb594e9609',
            // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
            onesignal_google_project_number: 'REMOTE'
    ]
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'


    }
}
}
```

Below are my current dependencies

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
implementation 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'

implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.3.1'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.5'
implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.5'
implementation 'com.github.delight-im:Android-AdvancedWebView:v3.0.0'
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
implementation 'com.github.myinnos:AndroidScratchCard:v1.0'
implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4'
def multidex_version = "2.0.1"
implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:$multidex_version"

implementation 'io.github.inflationx:calligraphy3:3.1.1'
implementation 'io.github.inflationx:viewpump:2.0.3'
api "com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.0.0" //slideup panel

//for dynamic link refer user
api "com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:17.0.0"
api "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:17.0.0" 
api "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0"
api "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0"
api "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0"
api "com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:17.0.0"

implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:17.0.0"
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0'
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:17.0.0"
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config-ktx:19.1.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx:17.4.3'
implementation 'io.github.inflationx:calligraphy3:3.1.1'
implementation 'io.github.inflationx:viewpump:2.0.3'
api('com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0') {
    exclude module: 'okhttp'
}

api 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.3.0'
implementation('com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.0.0') {
   
}

//for one signal
implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.15.0, 3.99.99]'



}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
```

I have tried with `ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'`
then tried to generate only 32bits `ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','x86'`
but nothing working for me. while i analyze apk in android studio it is not showing any lib directory also. I also tried with split with below code

```
splits {
  abi {
  enable true
  reset()
  include "x86", "mips"
  universalApk false
  
   }
 }
```

But nothing working for me

Comment: Android 11 (API 30) hasn't been finalized yet. From what I recall the Google Play Store will accept new targetSDK only after.

Comment: trying API 29 same result

Comment: And double checking the built APK by unzipping https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit#unzip-apks shows no 32-bit/64-bit library discrepancy?

Comment: i unzip the apk no lib directory is there